# Is a fill-color-on-selection bug?

Tags: gimp

The standard fill-color is working, but it not do whats is expected when selecting a region:

[image]

The selection do online do ugly algorithm that selects all them cut to the selection... I need algorithm that do the fill after selection, that is, the selection must be used as a barrier for fill color, like any other colered line. Whow to get "this standard behaviour" whith the selection?

PS: I am using Gimp 2.10 on UBUNTU 20.

Answer (score 2):

You can intersect the fuzzy select (more or less your "standard fill pink", #2), with a circle selection to get #3, but for #4 you would have to intersect that with a third selection (polygon using freehand select, perhaps). You can also delete the excess selection using the "Quickmask".

Comment: Thanks @xenoid, it is a solution (!)... But I need to do this procedure 100  times when I have 100 selections? Well, you also say, indirectly, that **Gimp really has a bug**: it is **so difficult** (near impossible) to do this so basic and important fill-color-on-selection behaviour... There are no easy way or plugin to do easy way?

Comment: The selection you want appears to be some arbitrary circle arc limited by an existing pair of lines (whose length is important?). I wouldn't call that a bug, at best a lacking feature, but if you cannot describe in precise words what you want , it is hard to tell the computer...